# Byte / Word Addressable

Tags: architecture

I am currently studying basic ccomputer architecture and require help solving the following:

How many bits are required to address a 4M x 16 main memory if:

a) The memory is byte addressable?

b) The memory is word addressable?

The answer is, like in most cases located in the back of the text book, but I want to know how to work it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you actually read the textbook?

Comment: For the benefit of future visitors to this page, would you please accept the current best answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27356938/3817111) instead of the current one with negative votes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

4M x 16 = 64Mb of memory = 67108864 bytes or 33554432 words (word is usually 2 bytes)

this means that last byte in memory will have address: 0x3FFFFFF (67108864-1) = 26 bits

last 2 byte word will have address: 0x1FFFFFF (67108864/2-1 = 33554432-1) = 25 bits

and if we consider 4 byte word - we have latest address 0xFFFFFF (67108864/4-1) = 24 bits

**UPDATE:** I wrongly multiplied 4M by 16, actually 16 here is number of bits, so correct calculations will be:

4M x 16 = 4 194 304 cells, each cell is 16 bit = 2 bytes

To address each byte, you need 4 194 304 * 2, so last byte will have address (0x800000-1) = 7FFFFF, ie 23 bits

To address each word (2 bytes), you need 4 194 304, so last word will have address 0x3FFFFF, ie 22 bits

Comment: Perfect, thank you! The book wasn't great at breaking this down

Answer (score 8):

Lashane is incorrect despite being erroneously upvoted. We're talking about being byte addressable, not bit addressable. In reality, we should end up with 23 bits on a byte addressable system and 22 bits on a word addressable system (assuming the word size is 16 bits wide):

Byte addressable: 4M x 16 = 2^2(4) x 2^20(1m) x 2^1 (2 bytes, or 16 bits) = 2^23, or 23 bits

Word addressable: 4M x 16 = 2^2(4) x 2^20(1m) x 2^0 (1 word, or 16 bits) = 2^22, or 22 bits

Hopefully this clears up any confusion that Lashane may have caused...

Comment: This makes no sense at all, but my upvote is locked anyway, sadly. You mean to say that you're multiplying the same thing by 16 bits and getting two different numbers?! 2^1 is 16 bits in the byte addressable way and 2^0 is 16 bits in the word addressable way? See Zhanwen's answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you are working on Chapter 4, No. 5 of Null and Lobur, here's the answer:

a) 23 bits

4M * 16 = 2^2 * 2^20 * (2^4 / 2^3) (16 bits / 8 bits is a byte) = 2^2 * 2^20 * 2^1 = 2^23 => 23 bits.

b) 22 bits

Assuming a word is 16 bits or 2 bytes long (reasonable assumption in Null and Lobur especially if you look the previous exercise (No. 4).

4M * 16 = 2^2 * 2^20 * (2^4 / 2^4) (16 bits / 16 bits is a word) = 2^2 * 2^20 * 2^0 = 2^22 => 22 bits.

Comment: This looks more convincing.

Answer (score 0):

That is incorrect Individual bits are not addressable.  Admittedly, the memory contains

```
4M * 16 bits = 2^22 * 2^4 = 2^26 bits
```

but it is the byte or word count that is used for the addressing.

Comment: Your numbers are wrong. Where did you get 2^22 and where'd you get 2^4?